# Raster predictions do not reproduce session to session when factor variable is included in model

Tags: r, session, prediction, r-raster, gbm

This question is related to this one I posted a year and a half ago: [Reproducibility of results from predict() function - raster package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298016/reproducibility-of-results-from-predict-function-raster-package). But since it did not have an example, I have created a new question also with updated information.

I have a somewhat obscure issue with reproducing my predictions to a raster. I am creating a gbm model with numerical variables and a single factor variable. I then use the raster package to predict to a raster using my trained model. The predictions vary session to session, but reproduce within a single R session. If I remove the factor variable, the results reproduce session to session. Also, in my below example, if I have more factor levels in the training data than in the raster variable version, I can get it to reproduce session to session. What causes this and how can I reproduce my results session to session while including the factor variable?

```
# This code will not reproduce session to session, but does if I leave many many factor levels in newwine with the
# commented out code

library(breakDown)
library(gbm)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

# leave in many levels and code will reproduce session to session
#newwine <- wine[1:500,c(1:3,6)]

# specify only levels which are in the below raster and code will not reproduce session to session
newwine <- wine[,c(1:3,6)] %>% 
           filter(free.sulfur.dioxide == 3 | free.sulfur.dioxide == 10 | free.sulfur.dioxide == 15 |
                  free.sulfur.dioxide == 37 | free.sulfur.dioxide == 76)

head(newwine)

# make free.sulfur.dioxide as factor variable
newwine$free.sulfur.dioxide <- as.factor(newwine$free.sulfur.dioxide)
levels(newwine$free.sulfur.dioxide)

set.seed(123)
model <- gbm(fixed.acidity ~ ., data = newwine, 
             distribution = "gaussian",
             bag.fraction = 0.50,
             n.trees = 1000, 
             interaction.depth = 16, 
             shrinkage = 0.016, 
             n.minobsinnode = 10, verbose = FALSE)

summary(model)
plot(model, i.var = 3, n.trees = 1000)


# make some rasters for the predictor variables
free.sulfur.dioxide <- c(rep(3,times=10), rep(10, times = 10), 
                         rep(15, times = 10), rep(37, times = 10), 
                         rep(76, times = 10))

free.sulfur.dioxide.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(free.sulfur.dioxide.r) <- free.sulfur.dioxide

set.seed(123)
volatile.acidity <- newwine %>% 
                    dplyr::select(volatile.acidity) %>% 
                    sample_n(50) 
volatile.acidity <- as.vector(volatile.acidity)[,1]
volatile.acidity.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(volatile.acidity.r) <- volatile.acidity

set.seed(123)
citric.acid <- newwine %>% 
               dplyr::select(citric.acid) %>% 
               sample_n(50) 
citric.acid <- as.vector(citric.acid)[,1]
citric.acid.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(citric.acid.r) <- citric.acid

# create a raster stack
r <- stack(free.sulfur.dioxide.r, volatile.acidity.r, citric.acid.r)
names(r) <- c("free.sulfur.dioxide", "volatile.acidity", "citric.acid")

###########################################################################################################################

# predict to a raster with raster predict
pred <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees, format="GTiff")
writeRaster(pred, "prediction1.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

###########################################################################################################################

# close the session and reopen, run until line 61, then run below to make a new prediction, called prediction 2
pred <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees, format="GTiff")
writeRaster(pred, "prediction2.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

# read in the previous prediction
prediction1 <- raster("prediction1.tif")
prediction2 <- raster("prediction2.tif")

# compare rasters built across sessions
compareRaster(prediction1, prediction2, values = TRUE)
summary(prediction1-prediction2)

# compare rasters built within same session
pred2 <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees, format="GTiff")
compareRaster(pred, pred2, values = TRUE)
```

However, the below code does not use the factor variable and will reproduce session to session.

```
### Same exercise but without setting the free sulfur dioxide to factor
## this code will reproduce session to session

library(breakDown)
library(gbm)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

newwine <- wine[1:500,c(1:3)]

head(newwine)

set.seed(123)
model <- gbm(fixed.acidity ~ ., data = newwine, 
             distribution = "gaussian",
             bag.fraction = 0.50,
             n.trees = 1000, 
             interaction.depth = 16, 
             shrinkage = 0.016, 
             n.minobsinnode = 10, verbose = FALSE)

summary(model)

set.seed(123)
volatile.acidity <- newwine %>% 
  dplyr::select(volatile.acidity) %>% 
  sample_n(50) 
volatile.acidity <- as.vector(volatile.acidity)[,1]
volatile.acidity.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(volatile.acidity.r) <- volatile.acidity

set.seed(123)
citric.acid <- newwine %>% 
  dplyr::select(citric.acid) %>% 
  sample_n(50) 
citric.acid <- as.vector(citric.acid)[,1]
citric.acid.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(citric.acid.r) <- citric.acid

# create a raster stack
r <- stack( volatile.acidity.r, citric.acid.r)
names(r) <- c( "volatile.acidity", "citric.acid")

#######################################################################################################################

# predict to a raster with raster predict
pred <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees, format="GTiff")
writeRaster(pred, "prediction1.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

#######################################################################################################################

# close the session and reopen to make a new prediction, called prediction 2
pred <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees, format="GTiff")
writeRaster(pred, "prediction2.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

# read in the previous prediction
prediction1 <- raster("prediction1.tif")
prediction2 <- raster("prediction2.tif")

# compare rasters built across sessions
compareRaster(prediction1, prediction2, values = TRUE)
summary(prediction1-prediction2)

# compare rasters built within same session
pred2 <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees, format="GTiff")
compareRaster(pred, pred2, values = TRUE)
summary(pred-pred2)
```

Comment: Can you generate some data with code? Without example data it is rather difficult to provide an answer. It would then also be good to show how the results are different.

Comment: Hi, the data is built  into the breakDown package. When you load the library the "wine" dataset is available and that's what this example uses.

Comment: Issue possibly related to the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121725/error-in-predicting-raster-with-randomforest-caret-and-factor-variables?rq=1. I can reproduce the results across R sessions if I fit the model with `gbm.fit()` and  set x and y explicitly instead of using the formula in `gbm()`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try to look at it (even though I think one should never save sessions).

Comment: I don't save the session, but rather make a raster prediction, close the session (don't save), then start over to make a second prediction. I then compare both predictions by reading both rasters back in. They should be exactly the same, but are slightly off. I compare the differences with `summary(prediction1 - prediction2)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear that this issue is not due to the `raster` package but due to the `gbm` package. After some digging, I discovered the `gbm` package was orphaned March 2017, and there is a new gbm package, called `gbm3` on github (not yet available on CRAN) https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm3. When you predict to the raster, you use whatever predict method your model type calls for (e.g. `predict.gbm()` for `gbm` and `predict.GBMFit()` for `gbm3`. It seems `predict.gbm()` just does not handle factors coming from rasters in models correctly. It may or may not be a bug, but in either case, this package is no longer being maintained. `gbm3` does the trick and is reproducible.

```
# This code will reproduce session to session for the gbm3 model, but not for old gbm model

library(breakDown)
# install gbm3 from github
library(gbm3)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

# specify only levels which are in the below raster 
newwine <- wine[,c(1:3,6)] %>% 
           filter(free.sulfur.dioxide == 3 | free.sulfur.dioxide == 10 | free.sulfur.dioxide == 15 |
                  free.sulfur.dioxide == 37 | free.sulfur.dioxide == 76)

head(newwine)

# make free.sulfur.dioxide as factor variable
newwine$free.sulfur.dioxide <- as.factor(newwine$free.sulfur.dioxide)
levels(newwine$free.sulfur.dioxide)

#set.seed(123)
# model <-  gbm(fixed.acidity ~ ., data = newwine, #gbm.fit(x = newwine[,2:4], y = newwine[,1], 
#              distribution = "gaussian",
#              bag.fraction = 0.50,
#              n.trees = 1000, 
#              interaction.depth = 16, 
#              shrinkage = 0.016, 
#              n.minobsinnode = 10, verbose = FALSE)
set.seed(123)
model <- gbmt(fixed.acidity ~ ., data = newwine, distribution = gbm_dist("Gaussian")) 

summary(model)
plot(model, var_index = 3, num_trees = 1000)

# make some rasters for the predictor variables
free.sulfur.dioxide <- c(rep(3,times=10), rep(10, times = 10), 
                         rep(15, times = 10), rep(37, times = 10), 
                         rep(76, times = 10))

free.sulfur.dioxide.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(free.sulfur.dioxide.r) <- free.sulfur.dioxide

set.seed(123)
volatile.acidity <- newwine %>% 
                    dplyr::select(volatile.acidity) %>% 
                    sample_n(50) 
volatile.acidity <- as.vector(volatile.acidity)[,1]
volatile.acidity.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(volatile.acidity.r) <- volatile.acidity

set.seed(123)
citric.acid <- newwine %>% 
               dplyr::select(citric.acid) %>% 
               sample_n(50) 
citric.acid <- as.vector(citric.acid)[,1]
citric.acid.r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 5, -10, 5), nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
values(citric.acid.r) <- citric.acid

# create a raster stack
r <- stack(free.sulfur.dioxide.r, volatile.acidity.r, citric.acid.r)
names(r) <- c("free.sulfur.dioxide", "volatile.acidity", "citric.acid")

###########################################################################################################################

# predict to a raster with raster predict
pred <- raster::predict(r, model, n.trees = 2000, format="GTiff")
writeRaster(pred, "prediction1.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

# predict to a vector with predict
v <- values(r)
v <- data.frame(v)
v$free.sulfur.dioxide <- as.factor(v$free.sulfur.dioxide)
vpred <- predict(model, v, n.trees = 2000)
write.table(vpred, "vector_predict.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

###########################################################################################################################

# close the session and reopen, run until #### line, then run below to make a new prediction, called prediction 2
pred <- raster::predict(r, model, n.trees = 2000, format="GTiff")
writeRaster(pred, "prediction2.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

# predict to a vector with predict
v <- values(r)
v <- data.frame(v)
v$free.sulfur.dioxide <- as.factor(v$free.sulfur.dioxide)
vpred <- predict(model, v, n.trees = 2000)
write.table(vpred, "vector_predict2.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

# read in the previous prediction
prediction1 <- raster("prediction1.tif")
prediction2 <- raster("prediction2.tif")

# compare rasters built across sessions
compareRaster(prediction1, prediction2, values = TRUE)
summary(prediction1-prediction2)

# compare rasters built within same session
pred2 <- raster::predict(r, model, n.trees = 2000, format="GTiff", factors = f)
compareRaster(pred, pred2, values = TRUE)

# compare the vector predictions
p1 <- read.delim("vector_predict.txt")
p2 <- read.delim("vector_predict2.txt")

plot(p1$x,p2$x)

summary(p1$x - p2$x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but an attempt at closing in on the problem. It seems to me that this is not related to `raster`.

When I do:

```
v <- values(r)
pred <- predict(model, data.frame(v), n.trees = model$n.trees)
rpred <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees)
```

Quit, save the session, start a new session and do:

```
library(gbm)
library(raster)
pred2 <- predict(model, data.frame(v), n.trees = model$n.trees )
rpred2 <- predict(r, model, n.trees = model$n.trees)
```

I see that the values of `pred` and `pred2` are not quite the same. (see `plot(pred, pred2)`. However, the values of `pred2` and `rpred2` are the same: `plot(values(rpred2), pred2)`.

Alternatively, when I save `pred` (`saveRDS(pred, 'pred.rds')`, and I load it into a fresh session `pred1 <- readRDS(pred.rds)`, the results are not quite the same.

It suggests to me that there is some randomization going on somewhere in `gbm` that is not controlled by `set.seed`.

Comment: Do you mean the values of rpred and rpred2 are the same?

Comment: No, they are not, but they are the same as pred and pred2. That is, it seems that the difference originates in gbm.predict; and not in raster::predict.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see that. However, if I predict to the training data with `tpred <- predict(model, newwine, n.trees = model$n.trees` the results are identical each time I predict in a new session. Does `values()` do any conversions to the factor variables?

Comment: `class(data.frame(v)$free.sulfur.dioxide)` returns numeric.

Comment: If I do this: `v <- values(r)`
`v <- data.frame(v)`
`v$free.sulfur.dioxide <- as.factor(v$free.sulfur.dioxide)`
`vpred <- predict(model, v, n.trees = model$n.trees)` it will reproduce session to session.

Comment: we also tried predicting from a raster stack with random forest and it is reproducible, so it appears the gbm predict was causing the issue.